# Getting a page according to the value passed in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a network monitoring application in java using spring framework. It lists all the resources in the network. By clicking at one of the resource ids the page must redirect to a new page which displays all details of that resource. This way the next page changes with new contents according to the resource id we clicked.
Now I just connected the next page by mapping the page in controller, but the page is empty, i.e. the value is not passed to the controller correctly.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deviceInformation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deviceinfo(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<NetworkInterface> list = inventoryService.getNetworkInterfaces("");
    List<NetworkService> list2 = inventoryService.getNetworkServices("ipResource.discoveredName");
    List<Equipment> list3 = inventoryService.getEquipments("resourceId");
    List<Processor> list4 = inventoryService.getProcessors("hostId");
    List<SoftwareRunning> list5 = inventoryService.getSoftwaresRunning("hostId");
    List<StorageDisk> list6 = inventoryService.getStorageDisks("hostId");
    List<StorageMemory> list7 = inventoryService.getStorageMemories("hostId");

    model.addAttribute("INlist", list);
    model.addAttribute("Serlist", list2);
    model.addAttribute("Eqlist", list3);
    model.addAttribute("Prolist", list4);
    model.addAttribute("SRlist", list5);
    model.addAttribute("Storlist", list6);
    model.addAttribute("StoMry", list7);

    return "inventory/deviceInformation";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/interfaceList/{ipResource.discoveredName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getInterface(@PathVariable String resourceId, HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Got request param: " + resourceId);

    List<NetworkInterface> list = inventoryService.getNetworkInterfaces("resID");
    List<NetworkService> list2 = inventoryService.getNetworkServices("ipResource.discoveredName");
    List<Equipment> list3 = inventoryService.getEquipments("ipResource.discoveredName");
    List<Processor> list4 = inventoryService.getProcessors("hostId");
    List<SoftwareRunning> list5 = inventoryService.getSoftwaresRunning("hostId");
    List<StorageDisk> list6 = inventoryService.getStorageDisks("hostId");
    List<StorageMemory> list7 = inventoryService.getStorageMemories("hostId");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/inventory/deviceInformation");
    modelAndView.addObject("INlist", list);
    modelAndView.addObject("Serlist", list2);
    modelAndView.addObject("Eqlist", list3);
    modelAndView.addObject("Prolist", list4);
    modelAndView.addObject("SRlist", list5);
    modelAndView.addObject("Storlist", list6);
    modelAndView.addObject("StoMry", list7);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: empty page and empty value are two different issues, which one you are facing? I reckon you put a javascript alert in your "next page" in order to make sure request been forward to the right jsp file. If alert does not work, check your spring view resolver config.
If the mapping is correct(I mean alert works), you might need to take look into your controller and make sure the value is added into your model if your controller returns Model or ModelAndView.

Comment: also, keep your eyes on log file(I hope you have one), cuz there are million possibilities causing empty page/value.
by the way, if you do not have system log, check http response code would help you to identify what kind of issue is.
200: possibly the controller is not populating the data and sending to the view
404: most likely spring mvc configuration issue
500: emmm, you got a trouble :)

Comment: i want to load  my page with values according to the resourceid passed..now i get page with empty value..the resourceid is not passing

Comment: here deviceInformation.jsp is the page which displays details according to the resource id passed..

Comment: try change your controller return type to ModelAndView and add your data into that ModelAndView

Comment: changed controller with above changes..but now deviceinformation page is not getting on clicking on one of the resource id represented in row data..

Comment: hello,
  i want to redirect to another jsp page on clicking a link in table..link is created in the each row data..it must be redirect a page with that value which is clicked...and pass the value to next page and next page displays data s depends on the value clicked..how to write this controller code in spring mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample, which has a spring controller and two jsp files. This sample is just for helping purpose and it does not mean the best practice of using spring MVC.
Controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getdevices")
    public ModelAndView generateTable(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("table");
        List<Device> devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        devices.add(new Device(1,"Iphone5",500.00));
        devices.add(new Device(1,"Iphone4s",450.00));
        mv.addObject("devices", devices);
        return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/getdeviceinfo")
    public ModelAndView getDeviceInfo(@RequestParam Integer id, @RequestParam String name,@RequestParam Double price){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("device");
        Device device = new Device(id,name,price);
        mv.addObject("device", device);
        return mv;
    }
```

table.jsp (generating list of devices with links to each individual device info page)

```
<ul>
<c:forEach var="device" items="${devices}">
    <li><a href="getdeviceinfo?id=${device.id}&name=${device.name}&price=${device.price}">${device.name}</a></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

device.jsp (info of individual device)

```
<body>
${device.name}
</body>
```

device.java (simple pojo)

```
public Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;

    public Device(Integer id, String name, Double price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
```

note: I've noticed that in your latest code, you have set your View as "/inventory/deviceInformation". I'm not sure what your web app structure looks like. The value of View relies on how your structured jsp files under web root as well as prefix of spring view resolver.
For instance, in my testing spring web app, I have table.jsp and device.jsp right under /webapp/WEB-INF/views and spring config is like

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

so as you can see, in the controller above, there is no leading slash in the View, e.g. new ModelAndView("table.jsp)

Comment: If we just simply talk about how to pass data around across multiple pages and leave spring out of this discussion, you may find out there are basically quite a few different approaches to achieve it.
1. append data in url and use request.getParameter("para") to retrieve data
2. use request.getAttribute() and request.setAttribute()
3. html form and http post is another option for sending data to back-end